# Hide product titles within concrete category

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, opencart

I want to hide the product name in my Opencart shop only on one of the categories.

The name is displayed with this code:

```
html += '<div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
```

I want to tell that javascript something like this:

"If you are NOT in the the category with the route `index.php?route=product/category&path=59` show me that line.".

So that show the product name in all categories except in the category with ID 59.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, instead of using JavaScript I'd tend to use PHP...

Let's assume the desired category ID, where the product names should be hidden (not displayed), is `45`;

Edit the template file `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/product/category.tpl`:

- search for a line like this:

`<a href="<?php echo $products[$j]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?></a>`

- replace with:

```php
<?php if($_GET['path'] != 45) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $products[$j]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the simplest solution using just `$_GET` and manualy set `category_id` to `45`. It would be better to have this set programatically and from within the controller.

Comment: Great I get to the same solution after trying almost everything. Thats exactly what I am using. I have not the same luck to do the same when you cant to add some code inside the products of a category. If for example you are in a product "T-Shirt 1" of category T-Shirts how can I filter that "I am on a product of category 45 so I want to show this ___ " ?

Comment: @MZBS I am not quite sure I do understand Your additional question... Do You mean the opposite of hiding product's title - so showing something different?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?
Edit:

```
 if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("index.php?route=product/category&path=59")<0){
        html += '<div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
    }
```

Evalution was wrong, hence edit - what the code does: if current address does not contain given path execute second line, let me know if that solves your problem ;)

Comment: Hello, with that is no visible on any category of my shop. Thanks

Comment: @MZBS if this solved Your problem, please, accept this answer by clicking on the tick on the left. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @shadyyx Still not solved, is not detecting the window location and hide the element in all my website. Also I have tried with something like this: <?php 
      if(!empty($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'product/category&path=59') : ?>
      <style>.content .product-grid .name {visibility:hidden; display:none;  }</style>
      <?php else: ?>
      <style>.content .product-grid .name {display:block;  }</style>
      <?php endif; ?> and is also not working :(